# Meteor pub/sub not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

Here is my route that triggers the subscribe

```
   Router.route('listView', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'listViewTemplate',
        waitOn: function(){
            Meteor.subscribe('lists');
        }
    });
```

My publish method

```
Meteor.publish('lists', function(){
     return listCollection.find();
});
```

And the template that renders them to the view

```
    <template name='listViewTemplate'>
        <ul class='listViewList'>
            <li class='listViewEntry'>
                {{#each listCollection}}
                    <b>{{title}}</b>, {{description}}
                {{/each}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </template>
```

When I enter a record through the command line, nothing happens, but `collection.find().fetch()` ensures that they are being persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you've added a helper too:

```
Template.listViewTemplate.helpers({
    listCollection: function() {
        return listCollection.find();
    }
});
```

Also don't forget to return a value on your `waitOn`:

```
waitOn: function(){
   return Meteor.subscribe('lists');
}
```

When using `waitOn` you also need a `loadingTemplate`

```
<template name="loading">Loading</template>
```

and also add the `loadingTemplate` definition into the route:

```
Router.route('listView', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'listViewTemplate',
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe('lists');
    },
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});
```

If you get a blank screen or something instead it might be worth looking at the Javascript error log in your browser to see where the issue is.

Comment: so one must still use a template helper even with pub/sub?

Comment: Yes - you either need to add a template helper, or you need to assign a data context from your route.